# How to use colors from a pgfplots colormap in pie chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, pgf-pie

I like the pie chart from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart/, but it's in grey color.

Then I found the modified version to add colors by "Sigur" here:[How to give different color to each pie?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151078/how-to-give-different-color-to-each-pie?lq=1)

but still, I need to specify the color by name.

Is there anyway to incorporate colormap as here (by Ronny):[How to use colors from a pgfplots colormap in own draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276367/how-to-use-colors-from-a-pgfplots-colormap-in-own-draw)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\tikzset{ellC/.style={/utils/exec={\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{#1}},%
    draw=mapped color!80!black, fill=mapped color!80!white}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[hide axis,
            colormap/hsv,
            xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
            ymin=-.5, ymax=.5,
            axis equal]
        \draw[ellC=0, rotate around={-20:(0,0)}] (0,0) ellipse (.5 and .25);
        \draw[ellC=50, rotate around={0:(1,0)}] (1,0) ellipse (.45 and .3);
        \draw[ellC=100, rotate around={20:(2,0)}] (2,0) ellipse (.4 and **strong text**.35);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

into those pie chart example.

Comment: I think stefan's answer solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

Adapting [Stefan's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286837/1952) to [Sigur's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151081/1952), a possible solution could be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\tikzset{
    mycolor/.style={
        color of colormap={#1},
        fill=.!30,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\slice}[5]{ %% use 5 arguments here
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  \let\midangle\pgfmathresult

  % slice %% I changed !10 to !30 to get darker color
  % use the fifth argument #5 to pass the color  
  \draw[thick, mycolor={#5}] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

  % outer label
  \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

  % inner label
  \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  \let\temp\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
  \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
  \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
%% -------------- use the new variable \c to pass the color
\foreach \p/\t [evaluate=\p as \color using \p*25] in {20/type A, 4/type B, 11/type C, 49/type D, 16/other}
  {
    \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
    \addtocounter{b}{\p}
    \slice{\thea/100*360}
          {\theb/100*360}
          {\p\%}{\t}{\color}  %% here we use the fifth variable
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The color used in this case is comuputed with `\p*25` where `\p` corresponds to the pie section. You'll have to decide which mapping to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The same with PSTricks. Run the example with `xelatex` or `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psframebox*[fillcolor=yellow!80!black!10]{%
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psChart[userColor={red!30,green!30,
    blue!40,cyan!40,magenta!60}]{ 20, 4, 11, 49, 16 }{1}{2.75}
\pgfforeach \iA/\iB/\iC in {1/20/A,2/4/B,3/11/C,4/49/D,5/16/E}{%
     \rput(psChartI\iA){\small\iB\%}%
     \ncline[nodesepA=0.4,nodesepB=0.75]{psChartI\iA}{psChartO\iA}%
     \ncput[npos=1.2]{\small\iC}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\psChart[options]{data}{list of marked elements}{radius`}