# Include Inkscape in pdfLaTeX problem

Tags: inkscape

I have the following problem to include a pdf (also tried eps) to a latex document. I always get this fault:

```
    ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpicture ->\egroup \hss \egroup 
                                   \ht \@picbox \@picht \dp \@picbox \z@ \mb...
l.121   \end{picture}
                     %
```

When I count the { and }'s I see one more } ! But I cannot find the point where this i could be.

I also checked my text in the document and tried it without text.

Also I think there is a Bug in Inkscape. When I am making the pdf and the tex file, the pdf file has only 1 page, but the tex document tries to include page 1-4. So I have to remove this code lines. After this the error described above comes up.

Anyone has an idea about all this?

Thanks

edit:

The .pdf_tex file looks like this: 
As you can see there are the

```
 \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=
```

lines. When I delete this lines everything works fine. But with them I get an error like:

```
page does not exist <1>
```

It always shows the last available page in the PDF document.

```
    \begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{435.32183943bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.50752079)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{circuit_grid.pdf}}%
    \put(0.37340864,0.37886437){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{circuit_grid.pdf}}%
    \put(0.62573349,0.26491124){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=3]{circuit_grid.pdf}}%
    \put(0.2106184,0.36258536){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0.79666323,0.32188779){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=4]{circuit_grid.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Which package do you use to include the pdf? Please provide a minimal working example!

Comment: I think you need to edit the question to give some hints that allow people to help. just giving an error message with no hint of the input doesn't make it easy to debug.

Comment: Ok I it works now. I found a } in my text. It is late and my eyes seems to need some sleep :D

But the 2nd problem I described is there furthermore.

Comment: Second problem? Please update the question and remove the resolved issue, just showing what actually troubles you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem is with pdf_tex including extra pages. You can have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243499/sharelatex-pdf-inclusion-required-page-does-not-exist-5). I had the same problem, I solved it by removing inclusions of "unused" pages. In my case, the "useful" pages were the ones just before including axis labels (it was 2D graphs). You can experiment and delete all pages but for one and see when it works, but I'm pretty sure that you can easily delete inclusion of pages 2-3, leaving only the first one.

Comment: If you point to a solution elsewhere on this site, does this mean the question is a duplicate?

Comment: I guess so, the only difference is in the linked answer the problem is that  pdf_tex tries to include "fantom" pages in the end.  While here multiple non-existent pages are included in random locations. It is similar, but it's not exactly a duplicate, imo. Plus, I didn't see, how I could mark it as duplicate, so I decided to answer at least.