# Insert figure created with Inkscape

Tags: graphics, inkscape

I need to insert a figure created with Inkscape in a tex document.

I have an 'images' subfolder where I store all my images.

In this folder I have some subfolders.

An insert statement works with relative paths except with the `pdf_tex` file Inkscape create, I wonder how to fix that (I do now want to put my images along the *.tex files...)

Then, all layer created by Inkscape doesn't appear. I wonder if it's a LaTeX related issue or Inkscape?

Here's the message error I get while compiling:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./images/my_image.pdf): PDF inclusion: req
uired page does not exist <4>
```

Comment: File > save as > select PDF format > check PDF+LaTeX. Then there is a PDF file along a TEX file in which there is the text and some other commands. This is the *.pdf_tex file. It can be normally included within the main document as describer in its the header.

Comment: Have you checked PDF file generated?  Does it look ok?

Comment: Actually not really, it has several "pages" and as far as I know, I didn't create these pages. I also asked this particular point on graphical design SE.

Comment: @s.k Can you try something? Open the file `my_image.pdf_tex` with your tex editor and search for the line `\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=4]{my_image.pdf}}%` Does it work if you comment this line? And how many pages does the file `my_image.pdf` has?

Comment: Yes, I have also figured out that page numbering within the *.pdf_tex file is not consistent with the real number of pages within the *.pdf document where the image is stored! It is the dirtiest workaround of my day but I can live with it for the moment.

Comment: @s.k Some time ago, there had been a bug in either inkscape or in one of the libraries involved in the export which caused additional "ghost" pages used in the `.pdf_tex` file. Try to update?

Comment: I just added the Inkscape PPA and upgraded to ver. 0.92.1. Same thing happens.

Comment: @s.k To avoid layers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243499/sharelatex-pdf-inclusion-required-page-does-not-exist-5/350175#350175

Comment: Apparently, this is an Inkscape problem, not a LaTeX/TeX problem. Can it be transferred to the question that s.k asked at the graphics section of SE?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Isn't it just about using `\graphicspath{{images/subfolder/}}` in the preamble? (and then including the TeX files in `images` and the PDF files in `images/subfolder`)