# Same font in figures as in document text, CorelDraw 2 pgf?

Tags: fonts, svg, pgf-core

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am in the midst of writing my thesis and I want my figures to have the same font as my text in Latex.
I have a lot of figures, so I would like the process to be automatic. for that purpose, I have found the neat *.pgf format that Latex can handle with

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

and

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{./example.pgf}
\end{figure}
```

With *.pgf files the font is automatically adjusted, which is exactly what I want. It works great with the figures that I created with matplotlib.pyplot.

**My issue:**
I have now created figures in CorelDraw such as [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzNLG.png).
I also want these figures as *.pgf so Latex automatically knows what is text and converts it to the same font as the rest of the document.

**My question:** Do you have an idea how to create *pgf files? Or is there another way of editing the font in my figures?

**My attempt to solve it:** I have tried exporting the file in CorelDraw to *.eps and using [eps2pgf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eps2pgf/) converting it to *.pgf. Sadly eps2pgf does not show compability with the *.eps file created by CorelDraw ([error report](https://sourceforge.net/p/eps2pgf/discussion/662858/thread/e910a15552/)). I thought I might be able to export it to Inkscape and exporting as an *.eps file there, but the conversion doesn't work either.

PS: CorelDraw can export to [all of these file formats.](http://product.corel.com/help/CorelDRAW/540240626/Main/EN/Doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=CorelDRAW_Help&file=CorelDRAW-File-formats.html)

Comment: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) can export to LaTeX → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz#151287 So maybe you can import your figures in or recreate with inkscape

Comment: Let me note that `pgfplots` is here sort of an overkill. It should of course do the job, since it is based on Ti*k*Z/pgf, but a slightly more minimal package to load would be `tikz`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, that's why it was slow :)

Comment: Never seen a pgf file, but I suspect that it resembles the legend stored in the aux file.  That is, it is full of TikZ basic commands, like \pgfpathmoveto and \pgfpathlineto.

Answer (score 1):

The solution via Inkscape worked! Thank you DG' for showing me the right direction! :)
I am not converting the file to *pgf, but using the export function of Inkscape like this:

1. Export the graphic as *.svg file in CorelDraw
2. Import the *.svg file and [edit it in Inkscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243499/sharelatex-pdf-inclusion-required-page-does-not-exist-5/350175#350175)
3. [Export it as pdf like DG' mentioned in a comment on my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz#151287)
4. After doing these steps I was able to import the figure in latex like this:
   this:

`\usepackage{tikz}`

and

```
\begin{figure}
    \graphicspath{{figures/}}
    \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
    \input{./figures/example_figure.pdf_tex}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

(Don't ask me why I had to specify \graphicspath, but without it, latex doesn't find the pdf file.