# Package SVG: the result is missing some parts

Tags: svg, inkscape

I managed to setup the SVG package so it would successfully import an SVG file.

Here is the full config:

```
\RequirePackage[width=\textwidth]{svg}      % In my custom package
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgpath={uml/}}{svg}  % In the file
```

I then include the SVG file (`uml/uml.svg`) with:

```
\includesvg{uml}
```

This works with no errors or warnings.

However, the original SVG file looked like this:[image: Original file] (Sorry this is awful, but you can't upload SVG files directly). Notice the arrows on the top-left.

Here is the resulting file: [image: Resulting file]

I'm fine with that, except that the three arrows on the top-left disappeared from some reason.

When reading the doc I found the `lastpage` option, however it is to fix a bug in Inkscape 0.91, and I'm running 0.92.1 r15371.

The SVG file was generated with UMLet (but that cannot be the problem, the first picture is after the generation). However, the missing arrows are the first I added when creating the diagram, that seems a bit too big of a coincidence -- however I don't know how SVG works so I don't really know if that has an influence or not.

[UXF file generated by UMLet](ftp://clovis.online/users/ivan/others/uml.uxf) | [SVG file generated by UMLet](ftp://clovis.online/users/ivan/others/uml.svg) | [Temporary PDF file generated by the `svg` package](ftp://clovis.online/users/ivan/others/uml.pdf)

---

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[width=\textwidth]{svg}

\begin{document}

\includesvg{animaux}

\end{document}
```

You need to add the file `uml.svg` in the same folder.

Comment: Can you share the .svg file (for example copy and paste the content of the file to https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: As a vector format SVG lines and other features can have several personal attributes. Two of these (visibility and opacity) may have been set for the first few lines then changed after that. Another possibility is Z order where those lines may be prior to a transparent border/frame which is later made opaque then the visible items are in the foreground. Simple solution redraw the missing lines worst case is some minor duplication unless the dead uns appear as zombies later.

Comment: @samcarter edited to include links to the files

Comment: @CLOVIS Thanks for the links to the files. Can you also add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question?

Comment: @samcarter added MWE

Comment: `width=\textwidth` is no valid package option of the svg package. Do you mean `\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{uml}`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug of `inkscape`. After the conversion of svg to pdf all pages above 25 seems to be missing in the `./svg-inkscape/uml_svg-tex.pdf_tex` file. You can edit the file and add them like in the code below.

To not accidentally overwrite your file, you might want to change the name and include it with

```
\def\svgwidth{\textwidth}
\input{YourNewName.pdf_tex}
```

instead of `\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{uml}`

---

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.91, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'uml_svg-tex.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{592.8bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.48717949)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.03036437,0.07219973){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Maladie}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.2780027,0.07137733){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Médicament}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=3]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.58164642,0.20633009){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Matériel}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=4]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.84075574,0.20633009){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Nourriture}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=5]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.57354926,0.07137733){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\textit{Stockable}}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=6]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.82726046,0.34128286){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Classification}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=7]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.31174089,0.46274035){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Rang}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=8]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.28340081,0.20633009){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\textit{Événement}}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=9]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.03103914,0.34128286){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Contrat}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=10]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.58704453,0.34128286){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Animal}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=11]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.2928475,0.34128286){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Personne }}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=12]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.39676113,0.11740891){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=13]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.98380567,0.31969042){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=14]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.07287449,0.11740891){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=15]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.28879892,0.11740891){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=16]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.23424845,0.04978489){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0.16059379,0.04978489){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=17]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.89608637,0.27245695){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=18]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.95006748,0.38731444){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0..1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=19]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.78801876,0.31969042){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=20]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.34278003,0.40740971){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=21]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.42802753,0.2214216){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1..n}}}%
    \put(0.49573064,0.28300648){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0..1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=22]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.34278003,0.25236167){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1..n}}}%
    \put(0.34278003,0.27245695){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=23]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.15770904,0.28228502){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=24]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.23471241,0.31969042){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0.16059379,0.31969042){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0..1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=25]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0.43049933,0.31969042){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{1}}}%
    \put(0.51764926,0.31969042){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{n}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=26]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=27]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=28]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=29]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=30]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=31]{uml_svg-tex.pdf}}%                          
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

[image]

---

alternatively you could do the conversion from .svg to .pdf yourself and prevent the creation of separate layers, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350175/36296

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My UML file will be modified often so I want a script that can fix this, and I really don't understand what you're saying here. Are you proposing I add this manually?

Comment: @CLOVIS yes, I am proposing to do this manually. This is the only possible fix from the latex side. If you want inkscape to be fixed, you should make a bug report for inkscape.

Comment: @CLOVIS Another approach: use latex to draw your diagram (e.g. with tikz)

Comment: Will the solution you gave work for other files? Since I have ~7 files that might need to be updated about every week

Comment: I used pgf-umlcd before, but in this case it's not possible because my team doesn't know LaTeX. Worst case scenario, I'll just export to PNG (since that doesn't require Inkscape) and include that, but it's just... ugly

Comment: @CLOVIS If they suffer from the same issue, it might work. But I don't know your files, so cannot test

Comment: They all behave exactly the same way and were generated the same way too, so I guess it's the same problem :)

Comment: Instead of png's I would rather look into pdf's. Even if they have the text embeded they will be better quaity