# inkscape: PDF inclusion: required page does not exist <1>

Tags: pdftex, svg, inkscape

Just like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243499/sharelatex-pdf-inclusion-required-page-does-not-exist-5) Inkscape produces a `pdf_tex` file that contains higher page numbers then the generated PDF contains. Deleting the line in question in the file fixes the issue. User [Martin Schröder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5763/martin-schr%C3%B6der) recommended in the comments to open new questions on here if this issue should reoccure with newer inksacpe versions. I created the svg file initially with an inkscape version that still had the error and since upgraded to `1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)`. Please find my files that exhibit the problem [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IjYwZyHwHSLvuf6jDC468oSqr6YpSE9s?usp=sharing).

This is the relevant part of the logfile:

```
(/compile/cable-turned-labeled.pdf_tex
<cable-turned-labeled.pdf, id=1, page=1, 435.84906pt x 438.56055pt>
File: cable-turned-labeled.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use cable-turned-labeled.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: cable-turned-labeled.pdf , page1 used on input line 56
.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 165.59853pt x 166.62796pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 57.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file /compile/cable-turned-labeled.pdf): PDF inclusion
: required page does not exist <1>
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I already moved everything into the topmost layer in inkscape, but the problem persists. It turns out to be very tidious to manually edit the `pdf_tex` file(s). What further work arounds are there? I work in Overleaf (and Windows as a local OS), so I cant even use a Makefile to automatically remove the bogous lines from the file. What other options do I have?

Comment: Wow, it's really weird to me that this still happens. Consider reporting it on [Inkscape's bug tracker](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/). The easiest thing for you to get around this is using the `svg` package. This will make your life easier in several regards. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973)'s a detailed explanation of how to set it up.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/4290 done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could give package `svg` a try.

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\noindent\includesvg[width=\textwidth,inkscapearea=page]{cable-turned-labeled}%
\end{document}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of package `svg`

Comment: thank you! does that work on overleaf?

Comment: yes, works as advertised, also on overleaf. problem solved.