# Drawing pie skill chart for resume

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to do a fancy resume and I want to include in it a pie skill chart (see image below). Any Idea on How Can I create this image in Latex.

Thank you for your help,
Cheers[image]

Comment: What are you trying to represent with such a graph? Anyways, can you please let us know what class etc. you're using by giving an MWE, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` to show us what you have tried? Thanks :-) Also, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5718/32374

Comment: Related (in terms of the concept and its utility or lack thereof, not the implementation): [UX: Displaying user skills with pie chart (in percentage)](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63524/displaying-user-skills-with-pie-chart-in-percentage)

Comment: refer to : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135393/how-to-draw-bar-pie-chart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have an starting point. A central circular node is surrounded with some wide arcs. Change line width, colors and angles according your taste.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large, 
     text=white, 
     border/.style={line width=14mm}]
\foreach \angle/\col [remember=\angle as \last (initially 0)] in 
    {90/blue, 125/cyan, 160/green!30!black, 210/green, 270/orange, 360/red}{
        \draw[\col, border] (\last:2cm) 
             arc[start angle=\last, end angle=\angle, radius=2cm];
        \draw[white, line width=1mm] (\last:1.3)--++(\last:1.4);
}
\node[line width=1mm, draw, circle, minimum width=2.5cm, white, fill=blue!80] {C/C++};
\node at (60:2cm) {Python};
\node at (108:2cm) {Other};
\node at (143:2cm) {Java};
\node[text width=1cm, align=center, font=\sffamily\bfseries\small] at (185:2cm) 
    {HTML CSS JS PHP};
\node at (240:2cm) {Bash};
\node at (295:2cm) {Android};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice use of \foreach capability. Where can I find description of all it possibilities? I have read TikZ manual many time and I didn't find anything similar.

Comment: @Zarko "83.  Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement", pages 890-894 in [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf)

Comment: Indeed!  Now I see, that my reading of this section have not been carefully enough. Thank you very much.