# Macro for pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to build macro environment for a Pie Chart that I have. So that I can use several times easily. I already have a code that produces Pie chart/Donut Chart. It would be a great if there would be macro for arc angle/size, colour, arc label, and label for a central circular node. I would appreciate all the help. Here, is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large, text=white, border/.style={line width=12mm}]
 \foreach \angle/\colour/\name [remember=\angle as \first (initially 0)] in {40/blue, 90/cyan, 160/green!30!black, 200/green, 240/orange, 295/red!70, 360/teal}{
    \draw[\colour, border] (\first:1.5cm) 
         arc[start angle=\first, end angle=\angle, radius=1.5cm];
    \draw[white, line width=1mm] (\first:0.8)--++(\first:1.8);
    }
    \node[line width=1mm, draw, circle, minimum width=1.7cm, white, fill=blue!80] {A};
    \node at (20:1.5cm) {A1};
    \node at (62:1.6cm) {A2};
    \node at (125:1.5cm) {A3};
    \node at (180:1.5cm) {A4};
    \node at (221:1.5cm) {A5};
    \node at (268:1.5cm) {A6};
    \node at (330:1.5cm) {A7};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the pie chart that my current MWE producing:]

This is the pie chart my code is producing at this moment.

Comment: First check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/package-for-pie-charts?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [my code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244477/1952) is useful. Nice!

This code can be adapted two a `\newcommand` with two parameters.
`\mypie` has two parameters, the first one is the list of `end-angle/color/contents` triplets and the second one and option to be added two central node (which can be `fill=..., node contents=...`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{xcolor} %<- already loaded by TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mypie}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large, 
                    text=white, border/.style={line width=12mm}]
\foreach \angle/\colour/\name [remember=\angle as \first (initially 0)] in {#1}{
    \draw[\colour, border] (\first:1.5cm) 
         arc[start angle=\first, end angle=\angle, radius=1.5cm];
    \node[white] at ({(\angle+\first)/2}:1.5) {\name};
    \draw[white, line width=1mm] (\first:0.8)--++(\first:1.8);
}
\node[line width=1mm, draw, circle, minimum width=1.7cm, white, #2];
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\mypie{40/blue/A1, 90/cyan/A2, 160/green!30!black/A3, 
       200/green/A4, 240/orange/A5, 295/red!70/A6, 
       360/teal/A7}{fill=red!30, node contents=A}

\mypie{45/blue/A1, 100/cyan/A2, 200/green!30!black/A3, 
       300/green/A4, 360/orange/A5}{fill=purple!60, node contents=Z}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we include `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large, text=white, border/.style={line width=12mm}]`  and `\end{tikzpicture}` in Macro.

Comment: @user3669801 Yes. Answer updated.